# insert null value in date column in access when date is empty

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I am in problem is that, i am using php ms access databse, when i am trying to update date in database its not updating, i want to update date field when user put date and when date is null column value should be null, my code following

```
if($cDate==NULL){
    $cDate='Null';
}
else {
    $cDate='02/03/2016';
    }
if($buttonName=="Update"){
    $sql_update="UPDATE 0D1_INDEX set C_date=$cDate where DN_='$mdn'";
```

and when date inserted it become time

Comment: Please show your database schema

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
Set Default Value to NULL in Database
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could use the `isset()` function to determine if the value of $cDate is null.

So you would have to do something like so:

```
if(!isset($cDate)){
    $cDate = "Null";
} else{
    $cDate='02/03/2016';
}
```

`isset()` determines if the value is not **NULL** so putting an `!` in front of it means that if the value is **NULL**